# Replace the current content of div with another page response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        .....
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <form>
                ....
                <input type="submit" onclick="loadAnotherPage()"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to load another page say **edit_profile.php** in the `content` div. How can it be achieved without refreshing the page?

I tried to use jQuery `load()` method. But looks like I missed something. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code that you *tried*, and what results did you get (other than "it didn't work")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click `submit button` it's submit form and page refresh that's why its not working.

**Instead of type submit set button and then set function `onclick`.**

```
function loadAnotherPage(){
    $("#content").load('edit_profile.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanx buddy! I guess the issue was with submit type only... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
           $(document).ready(
            function() {
              $('#load_file').click(
            $.post('edit_profile.php',
             {},
             function(data){
                $("#content").html(data);
             },''
            )
               ); 
                }
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
     <div id="content"></div>
      <button id="loadpage">load new page</button>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loadpage").click(function() {
        $.get("edit_profile.php", function(response){
          $("#content").html(response);
        });
    })
 });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```